# What is the best way to create a data table in android?

Tags: java, android, material-design, android-tablelayout

I would like to create a table which is filled by data **from DB**. I know that it **is** possible to create a dynamic table using ***TableLayout***  but I'm not sure that it's the best solution im my case. 
[Here is an example of what I want to create(the first table on the page).](https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/data-tables.html#data-tables-structure)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I'll give you my inputs on this.

If your data is limited and you are sure to display all of it in a single screen in a presentable manner, then yes, a TableLayout will suffice.

However, in a real world, flexibility counts so you should always consider the possibility that your data may expand in the future. Keeping that in mind, you should use a ListView or a RecyclerView in this case. Define a base layout for each row of your list or recycler view and then connect the data from your database to this view using a suitable adapter.

For starters:
https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html